# Is there any solution to hide a menu item in bottomNavigationView without removing the space given to the view?

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I'am trying to hide a menu item, and keeping the other menu items in their positions.

Here is my menu:
[menu before removing any item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVOIu.jpg)

I mean when I use this code

```
navigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.composeur);
```

the item is removed but other items change their positions:
[see here the items moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WS8N.jpg)

and when I use

```
navigation.findViewById(R.id.composeur).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

the item composeur is invisible, but when I click on another item for example "sms" it shows again.
[when using view.INVISIBLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFPm.jpg)

I  tried to use view.GONE, but same issue, the items change their positions!
I'am looking for a solution to how to remove an item from menu and keeping its space and not showing again when clicking on other items!

here is my class of navigationViewHelper

```
static class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

        static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
            BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
            try {
                Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
                shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
                for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                    item.setShifting(false);
                    // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                    item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR NO SUCH FIELD", "Unable to get shift mode field");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR ILLEGAL ALG", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
            }
        }
    }
```

there is no click listener for the bottom navigation view

Comment: Can you share code for click listeners of bottom navigation

Comment: there is no code for click listener , just a class for navigationViewHelper, see the post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.composeur).setIcon(0);
    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.composeur).setTitle(null);
    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.composeur).setCheckable(false);
```

These lines will consume space and nothing will be shown on UI as per your requirement.